# Flashmessanger message not being show in SocialEngine detail page

Tags: socialengine

I am using social engine 4.2.0 and facing an issue with flashmessanger. 
I am using this code

```
$message =  $this->_helper->flash-messenger->getMessages();
```

If I echo the value in my controller it works but not in view I am properly assigning it to my view with this code

```
$this->view->success = $message[0];
```

Interestingly if I put die in my view first half it echos my message but it fails to do so if full page is rendered. I guess some code of my file is resetting it.

Comment: Check if there's any other variable names 'success'. Also tell, how exactly you use success variable in your view and what value contains $message[0].